# Como receber uma diretiva dentro de um componente no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

Essa foto exemplifica o que desejo fazer:
[image: Essa foto exemplifica o que desejo fazer]

[Link para documentação da TOTVS AngularJS](http://tdn.totvs.com/display/THF/Validator#produto-menu-link-content)

Este é o trecho do form em que estou tentando fazer isso.
Estou recebendo os componentes `required`, `number` e `maxlength` dentro de `validation`.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="peso">
        Peso:
    </label>
    <input required type="number" class="form-control" id="peso" name="peso" placeholder="" ng-model="$ctrl.model.peso"
        ng-maxlength="5">

    <validation>
        <required>{{'componente_criterio.message_required_peso' | translate}}</required>
        <number>{{'componente_criterio.message_number_peso' | translate}}</number>
        <maxlength>{{'componente_criterio.message_maxlength_peso' | translate}}</maxlength>
    </validation>

</div>
```

O HTML deve ficar mais ou menos assim eu imagino.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <component-pai 
        diretive-field 
        . 
        . 
        .
    >

        <validation>
            <required>{{'componente_criterio.message_required_peso' | translate}}</required>
            <number>{{'componente_criterio.message_number_peso' | translate}}</number>
            <maxlength>{{'componente_criterio.message_maxlength_peso' | translate}}</maxlength>
        </validation>

    </component-pai>
</div>
```

Meu código está assim:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('App')
        .directive('directiveField', directiveField);

    directiveField.$inject = [];
    function directiveField() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: directiveFieldController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',

            template: function (elem, attr) {

                var html = '<div class="teste-passou">Diretiva recebida</div>';

                return html;
            }
        };
        return directive;
    }
    /* @ngInject */
    function directiveFieldController () {
        console.log('directive-field',this)
    }

})();

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('App')
        .component('componentPai', {
            transclude: true,
            // template:'htmlTemplate',
            require: {
                criterioFormCtrl: '^criterioForm',
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/componentes/form/componentPai.html',
            controller: componentPaiController,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            bindings: {
                componentPaiClass: '@',
                // directiveField: '<'     <- eu tentei isso mais não funcionou
            },
        });

    componentPaiController.$inject = [ ];
    function componentPaiController( ) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        console.log('componentPai', $ctrl)

        $ctrl.$onInit = function() { };
        $ctrl.$onChanges = function(changesObj) { };
        $ctrl.$onDestroy = function() { };
    }
})();
```

Como consigo o poder da totvs?

Answer (score 0):

pode pegar esse esses parâmetros dentro de um objeto no Agular e passa os atributos para diretiva, pois o angular tem o recuso de two way data bind, ou seja quando o AgularJs receber ele já vai adicionar lá automaticamente.